# MySQL Inner Join on partial word match

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, inner-join

I have 2 tables (star and moon) with column Product and using an inner join if there is a partial match, example of data

**star.Product**

```
ZigZagPress Stay WordPress Theme 1.0.1
```

**moon.Product**

```
ZigZagPress Stay WordPress Theme
```

The following seems to return a syntax error in MySQL Workbench (+ is not valid at this position)
my sql is a little rusty, not sure if the statement is correct.

```
select * from  applications.star
INNER JOIN applications.moon
   ON star.Product LIKE '%' + moon.Product + '%'
     OR moon.Product LIKE '%' + star.Product + '%'
```

Comment: Note: MySQL requires `CONCAT('%', ..., '%')` as `+` does not work on strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use CONCAT

```
select * from  applications.star
INNER JOIN applications.moon
   ON star.Product LIKE CONCAT('%',moon.Product,'%')
     OR moon.Product LIKE CONCAT('%',star.Product,'%')
```